Llama3 - Langchain irrelevant similarity search result
I have this below code for generating documents and adding them to my Supabase Vector Store.
import { SupabaseVectorStore } from "@langchain/community/vectorstores/supabase";
import { OllamaEmbeddings } from "@langchain/community/embeddings/ollama";
import { CSVLoader } from "@langchain/community/document_loaders/fs/csv";
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from "langchain/text_splitter";

const embeddings = new OllamaEmbeddings({
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:11435",
  model: "llama3",
});

const vectorStore = new SupabaseVectorStore(embeddings, {
  client: supabaseClient,
  tableName: "documents",
  queryName: "match_documents",
});

!async function () {
  const loader = new CSVLoader("./Travel-Destinations.csv");
  const docs = await loader.load();
  const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
    chunkSize: 500,
    chunkOverlap: 100,
  });
  const splits = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(docs);
  await vectorStore.addDocuments(splits);

  const retriever = vectorStore.asRetriever();

  const retrievedDocs = await retriever.invoke("Location: Spain");
  console.log(retrievedDocs);
}()

CSV is in this format:
Name,Location,Image
Angkor Wat,Cambodia,{imageURL}
...

I can see that my data is correctly splitted and added to my database, exmaple record:
Name: Alhambra
Location: Spain
Image: https://www.travelandleisure.com/thmb/3wf5cJtNM9ie_dAosvzk8u1ZqLQ=/1333x1000/smart/filters:no_upscale()/ALHAMBRA0117-73e53148f36748aca96a22a093af8a82.jpg

In the code you can see that I directly search for "Location: Spain" not even asking a question-like query but it still gives me completely irrelevant results, I even did a similarity search with score and still even locations like USA, Australia, Czech Republic are on top. I'll use the result data in a Rag Chain for further querying the LLM but I can't even get relevant results from search. I tried the same with movies csv and tried to query Drama genres but it returned me Horror movies.
Sample response from the above query:
[
  Document {
    pageContent: 'Name: Old Town Square Prague\n' +
      'Location: Czech Republic\n' +
      'Image: https://www.barcelo.com/guia-turismo/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/plaza-ciudad-vieja-1.jpg',
    metadata: { loc: [Object], line: 44, source: './Travel-Destinations.csv' }
  }
  // ... other irrelevant results
]

Why is my search results are so irrelevant?
